# make borders same size for several related elements on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have an issue with some div tags, as you can see the borders are not equal depending on how much content there is. How can you automate the borders of several elements to be the same size no matter what?

```
article {

    width:90%%;
    border: 1px groove #A17157;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 190px;
}
```

that is the box, this is the page

https://jsfiddle.net/codyc54321/ctp4n3og/2/

Complicated solutions in django templates/Sass are fine I just want these boxes to be able to be infinitely big, yet each 3 boxes in each row end up the same size (by box I mean the border property I used in the code snip to make the fiddle)?

Comment: did you mean box height? cant see difference in border width, 1px everywhere

Comment: yes, just the height. adding the min doesn't help, the boxes can be really big if there's a lot of tags

Comment: This looks fairly different depending on screen dimensions: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqgaGQ

Comment: this is on a laptop.  I mean it isn't bad, I just want the boxes to be clean and even. say of the 3 one box is really big, the other 2 don't know and will just fit their content. I want all boxes in a row to be the same size, which is different for each article based on its tags